# Determine size of object sent across the network

Tags: tcp, tcpclient

I am trying to figure out the size of an object that is sent to my application via TCP.  Unfortunately there is a third party tool that is receiving data and then handing my application an object through a callback.

Is there a tool provided with solaris that would help me determine the bytes of these messages?

Alternatively I could do it on a test windows version of the app.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a network analyzer, such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), to look at the TCP traffic.

Apologies if I have misunderstood your question.